# Generating URLs based on taxonomy vocabularies and terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have a Drupal 7 website and I have 1 Vocabulary "Interviews" containing terms Celebrity and Director.

I want my website content to be available at URLs like this:

http://example.com/interviews/celebrity/title

http://example.com/interviews/director/title

Answer (score 2):

In your Pathauto Patterns (Admin>Config>Search and Meta Data>URL Aliases>Patterns `/admin/config/search/path/patterns` ) in the Content Paths section, find the appropriate content type and use the Tokens (called Replacement Patterns) to fill in the field.

In the described case, it might be something like the following:
[node:content-type]/[node:field-category]/[node:title]
or
interviews/[node:field-category]/[node:title]

Be sure to expand and check what tokens you have available.